# httpservletresponse.redirect not getting redirected to react page from spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, servlets, httpresponse

I am trying to redirect flow from a java file to react page using the below code:

```
user.setIsVerified(true);
                    User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
                response.put("success", true);
                    response.put("message", "User Registered is Succesfull");                         
                try {
            
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("localhost:3000/loginafterverify");

               
          } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();}
        return response;
        } 
    else {
            response.put("success", false);
            response.put("message", "User Registered is not Succesfull!");
        return response;
        }
```

}

It is not reaching the mentioned page but the home page which points to localhost:3000.

The flow does not reach the spring boot file from an axios call in react. How should this be handled? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are calling this with axios you have to handle the redirect on the client yourself. The redirect will only be handled by the browser if the browser is controlling the request, it isn't as axios is doing that. However shouldn't that all be handled on the client anyway? So upon successful response handle it as well as unsuccessful. Looks like you are trying to do things in the server side that belong on the client side.

Comment: The request is originating from the browser and reaching the java file. I am aware that the flow should originate from axios and finally reach back to the call. But in this scenario, it is not so.. Is there a way to get the response back to react for instances when an axios call is not trigerred?

Comment: It is always from the browser **but** it isn't the browser that is controlling the request React / Axios is, so you need to handle it there.